# ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5 in google Colab

Tags: python

I'm trying to read pickle file in google Colab. Then it's getting this problem. I tried to updated the python version to 3.9.12 and it didn't work. I really appreciate the explication step by step [google Colab code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSaH0.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can pip install pickle5 and read your file this way:

```
!pip3 install pickle5
import pickle5 as pickle
with open('your_file_name.pkl', "rb") as fh:
  data = pickle.load(fh)
```